# Find the eigenvalues of a 5x5 matrix (Linearly Dependent)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the eigenvalues of$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 2 & 0 &2 \\
    0 & 3& 0 & 3& 0\\
    2&0&2&0&2 \\
    0&3&0&3&0\\
 2&0&2&0&2
  \end{bmatrix}$$
If I do it the usual way it gets messy. I can tell that the rows linearly dependent and that the dimension of the image is 2.
Can I can reduce the matrix to row-echlon form and then do the $|\lambda I - A|=0$ part? Or is there something else i'm missing?

Comment: Hint: It's very easy to see the three dimensional space of the eigenvalue corresponding to $0$.

Comment: For calculate the det you can operating with rows, remembering that det changes (for example if you alternate two rows, change the sign)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this matrix, I suggest inspection to find your eigenvectors and eigenvalues.  If you reorganize the matrix (interchanging rows and columns), it looks like the following:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}2&2&2&0&0\\2&2&2&0&0\\2&2&2&0&0\\0&0&0&3&3\\0&0&0&3&3\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This is a block matrix.

Consider the block 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2&2&2\\2&2&2\\2&2&2
\end{bmatrix}.$$
We can see that this matrix has eigenvalue $6$ with multiplicity $1$ and an eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity $2$.  The eigenvector for the eigenvalue $6$ is $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\end{bmatrix}^T$ and two independent eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $0$ are $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}^T$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\end{bmatrix}^T$.  These vectors can be extended to the entire matrix by extending them by $0$'s.

Similarly, 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}3&3\\3&3\end{bmatrix}
$$
has eigenvalues of $0$ and $6$ both with multiplicity $1$.  The corresponding eigenvectors are $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix}^T$ for the eigenvalue $6$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\end{bmatrix}^T$ for the eigenvalue $0$.

We can put these all together as follows:

- For the eigenvalue $6$, the eigenvectors of the *original matrix* are 
  $$
  \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}.
  $$
- For the eigenvalue $0$, the eigenvectors of the *original matrix* are
  $$
  \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}.
  $$

Since these vectors are independent and span $\mathbb{R}^5$, they form an eigenbasis and the $0$ and $6$ are all of the eigenvalues.

Edit: Due to the questions about the rearrangement, I am adding to this answer.  Namely, to put the matrix into the block form that I described, one needs to interchange the second and fifth rows and the second and fifth columns.  Therefore, consider the permutation matrix
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Observe that because $P$ represents the transposition of $2$ and $5$, $P^{-1}=P$ (or one can just multiply $P^2$ and find that it is $I$).  Using the notation of the original matrix being $A$, we have that $P^{-1}AP=PAP$ is the block matrix above.

Now, suppose that $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of $PAP$, then for some $\lambda$ (which can be zero), $PAP\vec{v}=\lambda \vec{v}$.  Then, since $P=P^{-1}$, we can multiply on both sides by $P^{-1}$ to get $A(P\vec{v})=\lambda(P\vec{v})$.  Therefore, when $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of $PAP$, $P\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: Why are you allowed to "reorganize" the matrix?

Comment: In this case, this reorganization is just changing the order of the basis elements.  You could represent this by multiplying on the left and right by appropriate permutation matrices (which do not change eigenvalues).

Comment: And what does this mean that the eigenvalue is "0"? I thought eigenvalues have to be non zero

Comment: Eigenvectors must be nonzero, eigenvalues can be zero.  For example, the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ has one eigenvalue of $0$ and one eigenvalue of $1$.  The eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue of $0$ is $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ while the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue of $1$ is $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: How do you know that the multiplication of a permutation matrix does not change the eigenvalue?

Comment: @PanthersFan92 It's a permutation matrix and its inverse.